# Making sense of phase portrait of simple mass-spring oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, phase-space, software

I'm new to physics, and I'm having trouble making sense of **phase portrait** of the following system,

$$
m \ddot{x} + k x = 0
$$

whose phase portrait is in [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PhasePortrait.html).

---

Since

$$
x(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{k}} \cos\left(\omega t + \phi \right)
$$

where $\omega := \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, once we are given $k$ and $m$, we are completely sure about $x(t)$ as a function of $t$, **except for $E$**. I think this $E$ should be related to how strong we pull or push the spring in the first time.

---

Can we visualize a movement of $(x(t), v(t))$ on the $x-v$ plane as a function of time $t$, given initial $E$?

Can somebody tell how can I visualize the movement? (e.g. website, MATLAB code, etc)

Comment: $E$ is fixed by the initial conditions $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$. Every different initial condition will give you a different red curve in the figure you linked

Comment: [via Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot%5B%7B%7Bcos%5Bt%5D,0.9*sin%5Bt%5D%7D,%7B0.9*cos%5Bt%5D,0.8*sin%5Bt%5D%7D%7D,%7Bt,0,2Pi%7D%5D). For matlab you should probably try the parametric plot function.

Answer (score 3):

The total energy of the system $E = \frac12mv^2 + \frac 12m\omega^2x^2$

So the graph of $v$ against $x$ will be an ellipse with $-A\le x\le +A$ and $-\omega A\le v \le +\omega A$ with $E=\frac 12 m\omega^2 A^2$ where $A$ is the amplitude of the motion.

[image]

So the graphs in your diagram are a series of ellipses with different total energies of the system and amplitudes.

You can think of a point on the graph moving along the graph with the passage of time.
For the system to move from $(+A,0)$ to $(0,+\omega A)$ with take a quarter of a period.

Here is a still from [an animation](https://physicslens.com/velocity-displacement-graph-of-a-simple-harmonic-oscillator-animation/) using [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en-GB)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The total energy is fixed by your initial conditions, so each combination of $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$ will produce a specific ellipse in the phase diagram. In my opinion, phase diagrams are easier to grok in the Hamiltonian context. The Hamoltonian for simple harmonic motion is given by
$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2q^2
$$

where $p$ is the generalized momentum conjugate to $q$. For our purposes, it suffices to say $q=x$ and $p$ is what we normally think of as momentum. [Hamilton's euqations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) then give us a pair of couple differential equations that we can solve for the position and momentum at a given time, which we may then plot to get an ellipse like above. To be explicit, we get
$$
\dot{p} = -m\omega^2x \text{ and } \dot{q}=p/m
$$

To get the phase diagram shown in your link, we may solve these two equations over many small timesteps and plot the result.

[image: Phase diagram of simple harmonic motion]

The trajectory in the top plot is parameterized by $t$, and the yellow dot shows the motion of the simple harmonic motion through phase space. The bottom plot is a quick schematic showing the corresponding location in real space.

The code used to generate this animation can be found [here](https://github.com/gplynch619/phase-mixing/blob/master/harmonic_phase.py).